# Strip last "-" if it exsits in a Hugo Shortcode using replaceRE

Tags: regex, markdown, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm using a shortcode in Hugo to wrap a heading in a link on a .md page so I can use anchor links on the same page.

The shortcode converts the heading to lower case and converts spaces and other characters to dashes. The problem is that the shortcode will leave a trailing "-" on the heading if the heading has a question mark or other character at the end. How can I strip the ending dash `-` if it exists?

The shortcode link-heading.html :

```
{{ $id := .Get 0 | lower | replaceRE "[^0-9a-z]" "-" | replaceRE "-+" "-" -}}
<a href="#{{ $id }}">
  <h2>{{ .Get 0 }}</h2>
</a>
```

The shortcode usage in .md file:

```
{{< link-heading "This is a String with a Trailing?" >}}
```

outputs

```
<a href="#this-is-a-heading-with-a-trailing-">
<h2>This is a Heading with a Trailing?</h2>
</a>
```

while using markdown for the anchor link

```
## This is a String with a Trailing?
```

outputs

```
<h2 id="this-is-a-heading-with-a-trailing">This is a heading with a Trailing?</h5>
```

The problem is the `-` at the end of the shortcode output. How can I strip that last - if it exists using `replaceRE` in the shortcode `link-heading.html` above?

Comment: [anchor links](https://gohugobrasil.netlify.app/content-management/cross-references/)
What's the issue with using the existing anchor links shortcode for Hugo?
Was their an issue their which you are trying to make a work around for?
(Note: if it's the markdown syntax - i.e. "# Header" creating a problem with blackfriday or goldmark - then use the alternate h1 and h2 syntax in markdown
Then use the existing Hugo anchor link shortcodes... Let me know if that resolves the problem at hand...

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be missing something here but if you just want to grab the `-` at the end of the string or if it's preceded by a `?` you can do something like:

- [`-(?:\?|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/DGcWDr/1)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do want to trim the trailing "-" if it exists (question marks are removed earlier by another replaceRE); but I guess part of my question is how to use whatever RegEx removes the "-" in the replaceRE format in the shortcode.